# Is route parameter name case sensitive in Web Api Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have just observed some strange behavior today with the names of path and the Action method parameters not matching in case of decimal and matching in case of string. This seems weird to me and I wanted to clear my confusion regarding the behavior.
To illustrate, I have the below code which works fine

```
[HttpGet("BillingPlans/{premium}")]
public ActionResult GetDecimalBack(decimal premium)
{
   return Ok();
}
```

But if I change the `premium` in path to `Premium` then  it throws Bad Request with message premium value is invalid

```
[HttpGet("BillingPlans/{Premium}")]
public ActionResult GetDecimalBack(decimal premium)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

But If I have some other string path parameters, it works perfectly fine.

```
[Route("BillingPlans/{LineOfBusiness}/{State}/{policyPremium}")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetBillingPlans(string lineOfBusiness, string state)
{
  // Logic goes here
}
```

I think I may be missing something, which may be something basic.

Comment: Asp.net uses reflection to map (or route) the stuff in the curly braces between a variable name and URL.  Variable names are case sensitive.  Other parts of the URL are not.

Comment: Tht's pretty understandable put I'm confused as to how the mapping between the path and the variable for string types match up though they are of different case

Comment: I used three of your cases for testing. Everything is normal and no errors will be reported. Please check the code you tested, or you can provide us with the detailed process of your test error case.